# Что-то не так: предложение не согласовано?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Осмотрев старинные здания, вышел к кафедральному собору, названному в честь апостола Павла и, немного помолившись (для проформы), направился в сторону побережья Плайя-де-Оро, название которого переводится с испанского как Золотой пляж.

Comment: Запятой нет после **Павла**. По согласованию - все здесь "так", не верьте Word`у. Он не может найти определяемое слово "побережье", поскольку путается с именами собственными. Хотя вообще-то фраза тяжеловесная, стилистика не на уровне. Но это другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы оформила это предложение так.

Осмотрев старинные здания, вышел к кафедральному собору, *названному в честь апостола Павла*, и, немного помолившись (для проформы), направился в сторону побережья Плайя-де-Оро, название которого переводится с испанского как «Золотой пляж».

Согласования в предложении верные.
После причастного оборота ("названному в честь апостола Павла") нужна закрывающая запятая.
*Золотой пляж*, мне кажется, необходимо взять в кавычки — имеется слово "название", которое, собственно, и переводят.

Иртыш (его название переводится как «Землерой») неустанно подмывал берег с Искером, и ныне от былого городища осталась только узкая полоска земли в пять метров шириной. [Алексей Иванов. Message: Чусовая. Части 4-5 (2007)]

Говорящий имеет в виду организацию, занимающуюся студенческими общежитиями, эстонское название которой дословно переводится как «Студенческая деревня» (Коллектив авторов. Русский язык зарубежья).

Answer (score 0):

А что здесь не согласовано, по вашим подозрениям? Тоже считаю, что предложение складное, только не хватает запятой.

Comment: Это не по моим. Предыдущий комментатор объяснил,"кто" мне об этом сообщил.